# How to compare date with time in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to compare two dates with time.But comparison is not working.

```sql
SELECT *
   FROM attendance
  WHERE     TO_DATE (checktime, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') >=
               TO_DATE ('01/09/2019 04:30:00 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
        AND TO_DATE (checktime, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') <=
               TO_DATE ('30/09/2019 10:00:00 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
        AND userid = '3825'
        AND SUBSTR (checktime, -2, 2) = 'PM'
ORDER BY TO_DATE (checktime, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') ASC
```

I was expecting output equal or grater then 04:30 PM and less then or equal 10:00 PM.But this date comparison is not working.Here is the 
 [Output of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVOWC.jpg).I want my result includes date and time between mentioned periods.
**Note:CHECKTIME datatype is varchar2.**

Comment: Is column `checktime` a `date` datatype or `varchar2`?

Comment: CHECKTIME is varchar2 data type that is the reason i am converting it before performing conversion and CHECKTIME is in format 5/07/2019 8:32:38 AM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need data for all the days(`01/09/2019 - 30/09/2019`) and the time of the day should be between `04:30 PM and 10: PM`.

You can achieve this using the following query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ATTENDANCE
WHERE
    TRUNC(TO_DATE(CHECKTIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'))
        BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/09/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
        AND TO_DATE('30/09/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    AND ( TO_DATE(CHECKTIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') - TRUNC(TO_DATE(CHECKTIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')) ) * 1440  -- converting difference into minutes
        BETWEEN 990 -- 04:30 PM in minutes (16.5*60)
        AND 1320 -- 10:00 PM in minutes (22*60)
    AND USERID = '3825'
    AND SUBSTR(CHECKTIME, - 2, 2) = 'PM'
ORDER BY
    TO_DATE(CHECKTIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') ASC;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: my CHECKTIME is in following format  5/07/2019 8:32:38 AM. So when i simply run this select TO_DATE(CHECKTIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY') from Attendance i have following error ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string.

Comment: Due to CHECKTIMEFORMAT your solution is not working.

Comment: Please adjust the format according to your CHECKTIME data. this is the solution for `DD/MM/YY  HH:MI:SS AM` which is mentioned in the question.

Comment: ```SELECT
    *
FROM
    ATTENDANCE
WHERE
    TO_DATE(CHECKTIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') 
        BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/09/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
        AND TO_DATE('30/09/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    AND ( TO_DATE(CHECKTIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') - TO_DATE(CHECKTIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') ) * 1440  -- converting difference into minutes
        BETWEEN 990 -- 04:30 PM in minutes (16.5*60)
        AND 1320 -- 10:00 PM in minutes (22*60)
    AND USERID = '3825'
    AND SUBSTR(CHECKTIME, - 2, 2) = 'PM'
ORDER BY
    TO_DATE(CHECKTIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') ASC```

Comment: in above comment you can see i already format it according to my format but its returning nothing due to the reason that  ```TO_DATE(CHECKTIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') ) * 1440  this checktime also formatted.

Comment: After formatting this ```AND ( TO_DATE(CHECKTIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') - TO_DATE(CHECKTIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') ) * 1440`` its not working!

Comment: <3  You've made my day!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your format by using such a format containing `TO_TIMESTAMP` conversion

```
SELECT *
  FROM attendance
 WHERE checktime 
       BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('01/09/2019 16:30:00.000000','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff')
           AND TO_TIMESTAMP('30/09/2019 22:30:00.000000','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff')
   AND userid = 3825
 ORDER BY checktime;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e6d33464a765ee779baef05be8a8b49f)</kbd>

**EDIT :** you had better to add a new column with timestamp datatype, and update your new column's data by using `TO_TIMESTAMP` conversion such as below :

```
UPDATE attendance
   SET checktime2 = TO_TIMESTAMP('3/09/2019 5:38:36 PM','dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM')  
 WHERE id = 3825
   AND checktime = '3/09/2019 5:38:36 PM'
```

Comment: @Barbaris when i tried your provided solution i came with the following error ORA-01843: not a valid month due to the reason that checktime is in  5/07/2019 8:32:38 AM format and in db its data type is varchar2.

Comment: it's a problem to hold a date type data within a string type column @ShahidAmin

Comment: ```3/09/2019 5:38:36 PM
4/09/2019 5:12:02 PM
6/09/2019 3:05:01 PM
13/09/2019 5:04:43 PM
16/09/2019 5:00:51 PM
17/09/2019 5:05:45 PM
19/09/2019 5:03:57 PM
20/09/2019 5:09:02 PM
23/09/2019 5:04:46 PM
24/09/2019 5:00:09 PM
25/09/2019 5:00:20 PM
26/09/2019 5:04:01 PM
30/09/2019 6:35:20 PM```  this is the output when i simple run select checktime from attendance

Comment: excuse me @ShahidAmin the problem is related with `checktime` within the ORDER BY Clause. That shouldn't be formatted. I've fixed.

Comment: My format is different. My format is "5/07/2019 8:32:38 AM" and the format your using is "01/09/2019 16:30:00.000000"